# How can one prove that a function is continuous?

Tags: continuity

I have the given function,
$$
    f(x,y)=1+\sin^2(xy)+\cos(x+y)
$$
I am wondering how can I prove that it is continuous on its domain? The limit of this function is 2 as x,y approach zero.  However I am not  sure how to use the limit to prove continuity on the domain D_f.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: sums, products, compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: Corrected f. Thanks for answers so far

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: continuous and differentiable everywhere along x axis

Comment: @MattiP. Corrected function